# Conditional Probability - two black aces

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

[image]

So let $A$ be the event the hand has both black aces.
Let $B$ be the event the hand has at least 3 aces.

$$P(A) = \frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{50}{3}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

EDIT:

$$\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{48}{2} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{2}\binom{48}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$

Is this correct? I got $\frac{2304}{19600}$

Comment: $A\cap B$ is the event that the hand has both black aces and at least one red ace.  You can calculate the probability with inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Note:  $\frac {2304}{19600}$ is much too small.  Thinking about the case where you have exactly three aces shows that the answer must be at least $\frac 12$.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Nevermind, i fixed my answer. I realized I was writing the events in a wrong order. But you're right, I did it a different way and got the same result as you @lulu

Answer (score 2):

We first need to compute the probability that the hand has at least three aces.

There are two ways the hand might have at least three aces:  it could have exactly three or exactly four.  If it has exactly four, then of course it has both of the black aces.

The probability of having four aces is $$\frac {48}{\binom {52}5}$$

The probability of having exactly three aces is $$\frac {\binom 43\times \binom {48}2}{\binom {52}5}$$

Thus the total probability of having at least three aces is the sum $$\frac {\binom 43\times \binom {48}2+48}{\binom {52}5}$$

To get the numerator, it's somewhat easier to subtract the probability that you have at least three aces but only one of the aces is black. Since you can have either one of the two black aces the number of these hands is $2\times \binom {48}2$

It follows that the final answer is $$\frac {\binom 43\times \binom {48}2+48-2\times \binom {48}2}{\binom 43\times \binom {48}2+48}\approx \boxed {.50526}$$

Sanity check: since it is extremely unlikely that the hand will have four aces, to get an approximate answer we can ignore that possibility.  Of course any three aces must have either the two red ones or the two black ones (with equal probability) so in this case the answer would be exactly $\frac 12$.  Our answer is slightly higher, reflecting the (small) probability that you were dealt all four aces.

Comment: I've a question, why do we need to compute the Probability of the hand that contains 3 aces first instead of the hand that contains both black aces? I notice if I compute that first I get the wrong answer.

Comment: I don't understand.  We are assuming that the hand contains three aces.  That means that the universe we care about consists of those hands that contain three aces.  Obviously we need to know the size of that universe.